# Doubts about using jsp include

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm starting to develop systems more precisely in java web applications using jsp'm more a problem that still can not find the solution. I have a file called `[header.jsp]` that is the links for CSS and other things that are important to my system that file is in the root directory. I have a folder that has other jsp files more when I try to do an include file `[header.jsp]` does not work, does anyone have experienced the same problem that could help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should work, is your path correct? Post the include path and the directory structure.

Comment: Actually wanted to know if anyone has any working example that I can buy with my code and finally whether I am doing the right way include or not

Comment: this is not the way to ask your question . should post what you tried not the problem statement alone.

Answer (score 0):

TestFile.jsp

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
<center>
<p>Thanks for visiting my page.</p>
 </center>
 <%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

header.jsp

```
enter code here
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
     <body>
        Hello from Header 
     </body>
     </html>
```

Same for footer.jsp

The include directive is used to includes a file during the translation phase.
This directive tells the container to merge the content of other external files with the current JSP during the translation phase.